# collections of free online pregenerated wilderness maps?

Tags: tools, maps, generator

Am looking for (out of curiosity, to begin with) collections of premade, at least medium quality wilderness maps available legally for free (published under gpl, gnu, creative commons, or a similar license), of all/any kinds of terrains/climates. Or, coming to think of it, for a good random generator for the same. Have you found any such that you'd recommend?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are some of the sites I use the provide me maps and such.  Some are free, some are donation. They are provided by the authors and are "no cost", but they do it for the love of the game. Please help them out if they have a donate button, they work very hard on these.

[DragonsFoot](http://www.dragonsfoot.org/maps/)
[Dream Weaved Worlds](http://www.dreamweavedworlds.com/Articles.html)
[Dungeons Unlimited](http://www.angelfire.com/rpg2/dungeonsunlimited/)
[Fanastic Maps - Jonathon Roberts](http://www.fantasticmaps.com/)
[Paratime Design](http://paratime.ca/cartography/)

There is more here than what you are asking for, overland, dungeon, interior. So enjoy.

Answer (score 13):

A nice random generator is [Hexographer](http://www.hexographer.com/).

Comment: +1 for this! I was going to ask a question about a random world generator and this does just what I need :)

Comment: Your link is out-of-date and went to a redirect page (without auto-redirect).  I updated your link to their new page.

Answer (score 1):

I have a [list of links](http://rpg20.com/about.php#region) to random generators that haven't been mentioned yet:

- [Age of fable](http://www.apolitical.info/webgame/map/)
- [Gozzys.com](http://www.gozzys.com/wilderness-maps)
- [Wizardawn](http://wizardawn.and-mag.com/tool_world.php)